# Check if multiple files with similar names

Tags: php, file-upload, file-rename

I have checked many questions about "if file or files exist", but my issue is that I would love to generalise this part of the code by asking if files (in my case pictures) with specific names exist. For example if I have a car that is BWM I would name this picture BWM_1 and so on for more BWM pics, and for a Volvo car I would do the same, I want the code to check this specific part of the car's model, just not sure how to do it.

I did check php manual and many other sources, I couldn't find anything, I did find something about putting it into an array, but what if more pictures are added then I would need to correct the code which I don't want to do...

Thank you very much and sorry for the long post.

Comment: _"Bayerische Werke Motoren"_?

Comment: keep going with [`file_exists()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and then Google to find "rename uploaded file php" and you'll figure it out. Just remember to preprend the name for it. If you have any problems, just edit your post to contain the code you tried. We'll be glad to look at it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner  I'll try it now, thank you very much for the lead

Comment: @xafierz welcome.

Comment: @xafierz Can you help clear up exactly what you're trying to check. Do you just want to know if any images of a specific model[make?] exist? Or how many images of each exist? or..?

Comment: @TCooper sorry for the bad explanation, what I was trying to say was that any image whose name starts with a specific manufacturer name would be displayed, so if an image starts with BWM, all of the images will be shown for that car, and because you cannot name the pictures the same name i have to write BWM_1, BWM_2 and so on, and i want it to display the pictures only that start with BWM

Comment: @xafierz No worries! just wanted to make sure I knew what you're looking for

Comment: @TCooper whooops, basically the second option that you gave me which was how many images of each exist, which would be the how many of each model basically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, writing from memory so will probably need debugging...

```
//this assumes you always start at 1 and increment by 1
$countBMW = 1;
if(file_exists('[~/yourpath/]BMW_'.$countBMW){ //check if any exist
     while(file_exists('[~/yourpath/]BMW_'.$countBMW)){
          $countBMW++; //increase count each time a file exists
     }
}
while($countBMW > 0){ //while some images haven't been iterated over...
    echo '<img src="[~/yourpath/]BMW_'.$countBMW.'" [other attributes you need]>'; //print them out
    $countBMW--; //decrease by 1
}
```

and repeat for each model, you could store your models in an array, and loop through that, replacing the hard coded 'BMW' text with the array values. You'll need to have a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) as well.

Comment: absolute top lad, thank you very much, the bwm_ part was spot on and exactly what i was looking for, i am very new and nobody was really showing this part or i wasn't looking into it enough, either way, exactly what i am looking for!!! thank you very much